# how to organize my csv file into Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, split

I have xlsx file like this :

[image]

i was exporting my xlsx file to csv file. So i get this result :

```
DemandID;ExceptionalFlag;TAG
47 417;"X78 Sos 
kopk";Enabled
41 224;"NAnCond
Blap
MOP
nbi
baze";Enabled
65 489;;Direct
```

i want to import my csv file that i will have like this output :

```
DemandID;ExceptionalFlag;TAG
47 417;"X78 Sos kopk";Enabled
41 224;"NAnCond Blap MOP nbi baze";Enabled
65 489;;Direct
```

I don't now where i will add this condition, you find as below My code is :

```
    var content = reader.result;
    var lines = content.split((/\r\n|\n/));
    var headers=lines[0].split(";");

    for(var i=1;i<lines.length;i++){
      var currentline = lines[i].match(/(\s*"[^"]+"\s*|\s*[^;]+|;)(?=;|$)/g);
   }
```

Please help.

Comment: I'd suggest looking for an Javascript CSV parser. There are lots of them available. 
 You could write the code yourself, but there's lots of small details you need to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not well defined, we don't really know where the line ends should be (it would be better if every value ended with ';'). If we assume that the last column can only contain one word, this gives your desired output:

```
const input = `DemandID;ExceptionalFlag;TAG
47 417;"X78 Sos
kopk";Enabled
41 224;"NAnCond
Blap
MOP
nbi
baze";Enabled
65 489;;Direct`;

let result = input.replace(/\n/g, " ").split(''); // collapse the string, split into array 
let counter = 0;
let flag = false;

for (let i=0; i < result.length; i++) { // look at every character in the array
  if (result[i] === ';') counter++       // count the number of ';'
  if (counter === 2) {                   // when the counter reaches 2
    flag = true;
    counter = 0;
  }
  if (flag && result[i] === ' ') {        // replace the next space with \n
    result[i] = '\n';
    flag = false;                         // and reset... 
  }
}

console.log(result.join(''));
```